# Bug in rails autoload_paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am encountering a strange bug in my code. I have a rails application with the following two files in the lib:

lib/module_one/module_two/class_one.rb

```
module ModuleOne
  module Moduletwo
    class ClassOne
      class << self
        def test
          puts 'Class one'
          ClassTwo.test
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and

lib/module_one/module_two/class_two.rb

```
module ModuleOne
  module ModuleTwo
    class ClassTwo
      def self.test
        puts 'Class two'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now my problem is, that when I go into the console and write:

```
ModuleOne::ModuleTwo::ClassOne.test
```

it throws the following: `NameError: uninitialized constant ClassTwo`

The strange thing is, that the problem seems to be connected to the use of `class << self` instead of `self.method`. If I change the class_one.rb file like this it works!:

```
module ModuleOne
  module ModuleTwo
    class ClassOne
      def self.test
        puts 'Class one'
        ClassTwo.test
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Im loading the files in application.rb like this:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Is this a bug in rails, or is it just me getting something all wrong?

Im using rails 3.1.3 btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Only a partial answer, but need formatting.)

It's because of how `class << self` works.

For example, if you change it to:

```
class << self
  def test
    self::ClassTwo.test
  end
end
```

it works fine.

---

*Edit; too long for reasonable comment.*

I'm poking around a bit... On an intuitive level it makes sense to me, I'm just not sure why yet. Don't know if I knew a real reason once, or if I'm just making it up.

I'm not sure why `self` seems to refer to the module, though; the "Programming Ruby 1.9" book doesn't go in to enough depth on the `class <<` semantics. I'll tweet something and refer to this question and someone smarter will create a real answer.

Comment: Hmm, okay - do you know of any resources that could explain this in depth?

Comment: See edit for preliminary thoughts, but yeah, I'm a little confused, actually.

Answer (score 9):

### Constant lookup

So first off, the basic process for constant resolution is that ruby first searches the lexical scope of the receiver (the class or module enclosing the reference) for `ClassTwo` and when it can't find it, it goes up a level (`Module.nesting` returns this search path) and so on. In your case that means looking for `ModuleOne::ModuleTwo::ClassOne:ClassTwo`, then `ModuleOne::ModuleTwo::ClassTwo`, then `ModuleOne::ClassTwo` and so on.

If that fails the ruby looks in the inheritance hierarchy of the enclosing class/module (e.g. has the superclass of ClassOne defined something. The `ancestors` method on module returns this search path. Lastly, the top level constants are searched.

### Rails autoloading

Back to rails's magic loading. Here a `const_missing` hook is added by rails that is called when ruby can't find the class, which basically tries to replicate this search logic, seeing at each step whether a file could have been loaded which would contain the missing constant.

Ideally ruby would pass the search path (i.e. the nesting) to search through, but unfortunately it doesn't: when you reference `ClassTwo`, `const_missing` gets called with just 'ClassTwo'.

Rails guesses the nesting by prepending that with the name of the class on which `const_missing` is being called (i.e. the class enclosing the access to the constant). For example, in your second example it ends up with `ModuleOne::ModuleTwo::ClassOne::ClassTwo`.  You can see this easily enough by defining `const_missing` to log what it's called with

```
class Object
  def self.const_missing missing_name
    puts "qualified name is #{self.name}::#{missing_name}"
    super
  end
end
```

Rails then strips off 'ClassOne' and tries `ModuleOne::ModuleTwo::ClassTwo` and so on up the chain.

So why does `class << self` make a difference? If you repeat your first case with the `const_missing` logging you'd see that the logged qualified name is now just `::ClassTwo`. `const_missing` is now being called on ClassOne's metaclass, and because `class << self` hasn't been assigned to a constant, it has no name and thus rails' attempt to fudge the nesting doesn't work.

This opens the door to a horrible workaround:

```
module ModuleOne
  module ModuleTwo
    class ClassOne
      class << self
        def test
          puts 'Class one'
          ClassTwo.test
        end
      end
      FOO = class << self; self; end
    end
  end
end
```

Because the class that const_missing gets called on now has a name (ModuleOne::ModuleTwo::ClassOne::FOO) rails' workaround now works.

Dave's workaround works I think because const_missing gets called on `ModuleOne::ModuleTwo::ClassOne` rather than the anonymous eigenclass/metaclass.

The real fix would be for ruby to pass `const_missing` a nesting. There is a [bug](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/2740) logged against ruby to this effect although it has been open for a long time. So yes, this could be considered a bug in the magic loading stuff (there are other edge cases) but the underlying reason is a weakness in the ruby api that forces the use of brittle workarounds.

Comment: +1; nice--I think your analysis of the workaround must be correct, but I dread trying to figure it out ;)